# Create labels from an array of values?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am making a stock market game and I want to display an array of int as labels.

I don't want to manually put it in for ever label. Is there a way to do this. I am using Visual Studio programming in C#.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your form look like? Can't you just use a standard (multiline) text area?

Comment: I would like to have a nice background so i don't think I could use a multiline text area. i have just used labels and set each on to the place in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a TableLayoutPanel on your form, so you can add controls to add and have them aligned and positioned automatically.

Then, to repopulate the labels according to your list of ints:

```
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();

foreach (var i in ints)
{
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Label {Text = i.ToString()});
}
```

If all you want is a method to get an array of ints and return an array of labels, then:

```
private Label[] GetLabels(int[] ints)
{
    return ints == null ? null : ints.Select(i => new Label {Text = i.ToString()}).ToArray();
}
```

Or without linq:

```
private Label[] GetLabels(int[] ints)
{
    if (ints == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var labels = new Label[ints.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
    {
        labels[i] = new Label {Text = i.ToString()};
    }

    return labels;
}
```

Comment: that should fix my problem thank you very much this will save me a lot of coding and time.